# Can I ignore 50 Ω trace impedance for eMMC?

Tags: microcontroller, pcb-design, emmc

I'm designing a PCB (4 layers: 1 signal, 2 GND plane, 3 PWR plane, 4 signal) for an MCU ([CY8C624AAZI-S2D14](https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/microcontroller/32-bit-psoc-arm-cortex-microcontroller/psoc-6-32-bit-arm-cortex-m4-mcu/cy8c624aazi-s2d14/)) that has an interface to eMMC (specs pictured below).

The eMMC ([AF128GEC5X-2001IX](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/atp-electronics-inc/AF128GEC5X-2001IX/12336501)) hardware manual (only available by request to MFR) says that the traces (for data, clk, etc.) should have a 50 Ω impedance with ground guards on each side of the traces. The eMMC is rated for High Speed 400 (HS400). The clock rate for HS400 is 200 MHz. The MCU specs shows a max. clock rate (in HS mode) of 45 MHz.

Can I ignore the 50 Ω impedance requirement because of the (lower) 45 MHz clock rate?

[image: mcu specs from datasheet]

Answer (score 3):

Yes you should apply the 50-ohm rule 10% tolerance. **For high density, you will need fineline track/gap and affects choice of supplier capability and cost for the 3:2 track/thickness rule with ur=4.2.**  The coplanar grounds do not affect impedance much compared to a very thin pre-preg (e.g. 0.09 mm) but they will reduce crosstalk significantly where needed.

The frequency limit is due to delay time but the impedance matching requirement is because of source transition time. The load is already mismatched, so it is important to match the source to reduce transition interference from double reflections.

A mismatched impedance will mess up the signals. The ground interleave tracks may be thin but watch out for track length.  It is easier to lower trace impedance to 50 Ohms with thinner signal pre-preg to gnd for 3:2 trace to h gap.

I don't know how much margin exists between echos and clock/data, but this needs some attention.

[image]

Below shows example
[image]

Comment: The first picture shows "length = 3.897 m". Does the "m" stand for meter? My traces should be no longer than 2 inches.

Comment: The intermediate capacitance delays that cause setup times were modeled with a transmission line. In other cases JTAG decoder delays.

Answer (score 2):

45Mhz is still high freq in PCB to get into trouble without impedance matched traces. Specify the impedance requirement to PCB manufacturer, they will recommend trace widths to be used for your stack up

Comment: I'm using altium. It has a impedance calc. I'm looking at 3mils traces and spacing. Vias are too big to trace out of this emmc package pitch (0.5mm).